# How to upload drag and drop image using multer in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multer

I am using Nodejs express and handlebars for UI development. I can upload the image files using "choose file" option very easily using multer. But drag and frop images cannot be accessed with multer.

How can I upload images added using drag and drop..?

**Frontend Form**

```
  <form id="form_id" action="/add_new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="product_name"  placeholder="product name">

    <div class="image-preview" id="image-preview">
      <img src="" alt="Image Preview" class="ip-image">
      <span class="ip-default-text">Image Preview</span>
    </div>

  <div id="dropFileForm" >
    <input type="file" name="imgFile" id="fileInput" onchange="addFiles(event)">
    <label for="fileInput" id="fileLabel"
    ondragover="overrideDefault(event);fileHover();"
    ondragenter="overrideDefault(event); fileHover();"
    ondragleave="overrideDefault(event); fileHoverEnd();"
    ondrop="overrideDefault(event); fileHoverEnd(); addFiles(event)">

      <i class="fa fa-download fa-5x"></i>
      <br>
      <span id="fileLabelText">
        click to choose a file or drag it here
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="button" class="save-btn"> save product</button>
</form>
```

I have write some javascrypt functions in the frontend to handle few functions for handling events in drag and drop area. I think that part is not necessary for giving answer to my question.

**Backend Nodejs**

```
//set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:"./public/uploads",
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,file.fieldname+'_'+Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname)); 
    }
});

//init uploads
const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits: {fileSize:10000000}
}).single('imgFile');


//add new product
router.post('/add_new', (req, res) => {

    upload(req,res, (err)=>{
        // return;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            if (req.file == undefined) {
                console.log("No image files available");
            }else {
                console.log("Image uploaded succesfully");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "drag and frop images cannot be accessed with multer"? Can you see on the network traffic whether the dragged-n-dropped file is transferred from frontend to backend?

Comment: I am passing the file with the name "imgFile" from the frontend. ```<input type="file" name="imgFile" id="fileInput" onchange="addFiles(event)">```  . With multer, I can catch it using that name and do what ever I want.   ```const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits: {fileSize:10000000}
}).single('imgFile'); ``` .  But drag and drop images are shows "undefined" when trying to access with the name "imgFile". Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: yeah, same issue here. drag and drop images shows undefined. There should be another way to do it.

Comment: AFAIK in order to multer take care of the data you should put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the input tag. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: Yeah, @calavera, Its already added. However, It helps to track the file when using click and upload option, but not for drag and drop option. I did this by setting the imgFile value, when it is calling onDrop event. Thank you all.